# Deploying site with Apache Maven SSH Wagon

Tags: apache, maven, ssh

## Introduction

I want that my Maven project(s) documentation (site) gets deployed at the docs folder of my website.

I'm using Apache Maven Wagon SSH at the moment to get the job done. The SSH connection works great, It pushes a zip file to the host and unpack's it.

I'm using fake names in these examples; `provider.com`, `company.com` and `company`

### Problem

But the unpacking is placed in the wrong folder...

Instead it steps through the dirs; `/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/` and create these folders to put the documentation in: `/${project.slug}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}`

It makes a new directory from the root: `r.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/${project.slug}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}`

### Question

How can I manage the SSH/SCP to connect `scp:ssh.provider.com`, than walk through `/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/` directories and finally create the directories `/${project.slug}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}` with the documentation inside?

### Apendix. Files

#### Log

```
: scp:ssh.provider.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/docs/ - Session: Opened  
[INFO] Pushing C:\Users\nberl\Code\company\company-maven-parent\target\site
[INFO]    >>> to scp:ssh.provider.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/./
Executing command: mkdir -p "r.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/./"
Executing command: mkdir -p "r.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/."
Executing command: scp -t "r.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/./wagon4192311672559342478.zip"
Uploading: ./wagon4192311672559342478.zip to scp:ssh.provider.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/

##########
Transfer finished. 40802 bytes copied in 0.064 seconds
Executing command: cd "r.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/./"; unzip -q -o "wagon4192311672559342478.zip"; rm -f "wagon4192311672559342478.zip"
Executing command: chmod -Rf g+w,a+rX r.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/
scp:ssh.provider.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/ - Session: Disconnecting  
scp:ssh.provider.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/company/company-parent/1-SNAPSHOT/ - Session: Disconnected
```

#### POM configuration

The distribution management of the site:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>company-docs</id>
        <name>Company Docs</name>
        <url>scp:ssh.provider.com/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/${project.slug}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/docs</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

The site deploy profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>deploy-site</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>site-deploy</id>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some research and a lot of just trying I found finally the solution!

In the distribution management sector you have to describe the **absolute path** from the **absolute root** of the server to the url.

Also you should use `scp://` and end the domain with `:` (see the example below).

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>company-docs</id>
        <name>Company Docs</name>
        <url>scp://ssh.provider.com:/home/user/domains/company.com/htdocs/docs/${project.slug}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/docs</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

Now everything works like a charm!